# Get standard errors from the output of the "ols" function

Tags: r, linear-regression, standard-error

How do you get standard errors of the coefficients from the output of the "ols" function (package "rms") in R? I know that "coef" gets the coefficients of the ols object but did not find a way to get the standard errors of those coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `summary`

```
# Example Data
Fact1 <- runif(200)
Fact2 <- sample(0:3, 200, TRUE)
distance <- (Fact1 + Fact2/3 + rnorm(200))^2
d <- rms::datadist(Fact1, Fact2)

# Model
ols_model <- rms::ols(sqrt(distance) ~ rms::rcs(Fact1,4) + rms::scored(Fact2), x = TRUE)

#Summary
model_summary <- summary(ols_model)

# Isolate SEs
model_se <- model_summary[,5]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work if, after running ols, I also compute clustered standard errors using robcov.

Comment: Hi @Giovanni - questions and answers on this forum are very targeted. In your original question, you asked simply how to get SEs from from the `ols` function. The answer provided addresses that question, and it is recommended you accept it as the answer in good faith. Your comment here poses a different/separate question that should be posted as a new question (along with sample data/minimum reproducible example (see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). I'm mentioning this because you are new here and your question has received some downvotes, so only trying to help.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I upvoted the answer!!